# TextMate 2: can the file browser [project drawer] be put on the right side?

Tags: textmate

in TextMate 2, can the file browser be put on the right side?

the old textmate solution does not seem to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the following command in Terminal:

```
defaults write com.macromates.TextMate.preview fileBrowserPlacement right
```

Comment: I had to restart TextMate 2 twice afterwards for the settings to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

1. Close the project drawer (view->hide project drawer)
2. Move the application to the left of screen leaving little or no gap on the left but plenty on the right
3. Open the project drawer - it should open on the right

Comment: not working. window moves to accomodate the extra space. (text mate v2, mac) but kudos for the ideia :)